# testing a c program that gets user input from the terminal

Tags: c, shell, unit-testing, stdin, assert

I am writing a program in c named: "shell" (i mimic a shell), and I want to write some tests to make sure I follow all the test cases, so I tried using `#include <assert.h>`

but I don't understand how to mimic the user input in the terminal. I tried using a file that contains a text and changing `stdin` into that input file and redirecting also `stdout` into an output file but it didn't work.

I also tried inserting the input to the terminal using the `system()` function but it didn't work as well.

example of how the shell program is running

[image: shell example]

### simple version of my C shell program

So shell.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    while (1)
    {

        fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);

        if (strncmp(buf, "quit", 4) == 0)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

        int fildes[2];
        pipe(fildes);
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            close(fildes[0]);
            dup2(fildes[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
            perror("exec error");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            close(fildes[1]);
            read(fildes[0], buf, 1024);
            printf("%s", buf);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so just copy and past it into a c file and compile it or use this online compiler I found to see the functionality better

https://onlinegdb.com/StEq1lNEI

and this is my testing program
So test.c

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    // change the output of ls -l to a file
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);   //redirects standard input
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout); //redirects standard output

    // run the program ./shell
    system("./shell");
    // insert to the program the command ls -l
    system("ls -l");

    // read the output from the file output.txt into a buffer of size 1024
    char buf[1024];
    FILE *fp = fopen("output.txt", "r");
    fread(buf, 1024, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    // compare the output of the program with the output of ls -l
    // if they are the same, the test passes

    // now how do i test the output of the program?
    assert(strcmp("shell.c \n shell",
                  buf) == 0);

    return 0;
}
```

if you see why it is not working please let me know :) would greatly appreciate that!

Comment: Would you mind improving the title? Mentioning something about "user input" (like what the existing answer addresses) will make it easier to search for your question on this site.

Comment: Please suggest an edit and I will update , for sure I don't mind improving question

Comment: "it didn't work" Please be more specific. What exactly didn't work? Show what input causes what undesirable output, and what you would like to happen instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but I don't understand how to mimic the user input in the terminal.

There are several ways to do it:

1. Invoke the shell with a argument that is a path to a script file (e.g.): `myshell ./myscript`.
2. Invoke with: `myshell < ./myscript`. It is the native shell (e.g.) `bash` that does the input redirection for *your* shell.
3. In your shell you can implement the `source` command.
4. You can write a separate program that invokes your shell under a pseudo tty (e.g.) `/dev/pts/*`, `/dev/ptmx` See: `man 7 pty`
5. Instead of creating your own PTY program, you can use the `expect` command.